Is ArrayList old and should never be use? If it is, what should I use instead with .Remove() method?
I've heared that ArrayList is a very old data structure from the early days and it should "Never" be use. I'm not sure if it's true but I would like to know if there's a better array type or something that will let me use .Remove() within my do while loop?
Brief description of my code: For each SSD I test-path if it's accessible, if not it will go to the next SSD, if it is available it will copy files and remove that SSD from the Array List so I can only try to run the loop again on SSDs that failed in the first run till i reach $maxAttempts or it will finish copying files for each ssd before $maxAttempts. Also if you think my code and logic can be improve please let me know, I'm still learning :)
Thanks in adv, happy to learn something new
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$DestSSD = @(
    "B:\",
    "A:\",
    "T:\"
)
$Source="c:\source"

$maxAttempts = 3
$attempts = 0


######__MAIN__######
do {
    $attempts++
    foreach ($ssd in $($DestSSD)) {
        Write-Host "Accessing SSD: "$ssd
        if (Test-Path $ssd ) {
            #Copy File below
            robocopy $Source $ssd /COPY:DAT /R:0 /np /tee /LOG+:"C:\Documents\logs\SSD_LOG.log"
            Write-Host "Copy successful!"
            $DestSSD.Remove($ssd)
            Write-Host "Remained SSDs to check: "$DestSSD.Count
            if($DestSSD.Count -eq 0){
                "Last SSD copy finished!"
                Exit
            }
        }else {
            Write-Host "Copy failed... Trying again!"
            Start-Sleep -s 5
        }
   }
} while ($attempts -lt $maxAttempts) #3 attemps with -lt (Less Than)
Write-Host "Max attempts reached!"
Exit


The better alternative for the array list is a list but for your use case there is really no difference. i dont see a problem with your code or with using an array list in this case

@SantiagoSquarzon Thank you for checking my code, I'll keep in mind of list for future project then.

The only thing I'd note is that currently you have max attempts for all in the list instead of max attempts per each item in the list. Not sure if that's what you want or not

Did your source say why it thought ArrayList should “never be used”? There’s nothing particularly wrong with it, least of all just because of its age, but other options might work marginally better in some scenarios…

@mclayton not really, just old and "never" use it since generic lists have superseded them. I figured that in my code it may not make any difference but I rather ask and learn more along the way :)

It’s horses for courses - you should avoid the array incrementing operator as well, but I’m guilty of using it an awful lot to write throwaway scripts that work with small volumes of data. When performance becomes a bottleneck I upgrade to ArrayList, and when that becomes a problem I switch the generics. I think a rule saying “avoid ArrayList” is counterproductive. Generics can be a pest if you’re using a library like the Azure Powershell cmdlets because you need to find out the fully qualified type name for all long autogenerated class names.

My advice would be use whatever makes it easier to maintain - go with Generics if that makes you happy, or feel free to use ArrayList without any shame :-).

ArrayList is Not Recommended, logic being "Lists are better than ArrayLists at everything, no real reason to use them anymore"
The alternative, as suggested by the docs, is List. Which works pretty much the same except:

you need to specify the type of object it's collecting(whenever in doubt, use simply [object])

its .Add() method does NOT return anything. No more nulling it! Yeah!


...which basically means you could just mass-replace all [System.Collections.ArrayList] with [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] and forget about it.
But please don't and check that everything works correctly piece by piece.
Also because you could maximize the efficiency by using the correct type of List. In your code it would be a [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] for example.
In your use-case there is not much difference.
as for improvements in the logic: there are a few.
# Arrays and Collections don't need end-line commas each line is automatically
# identified as its own entry
[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$DestSSD = @(
    'B:\'
    'A:\'
    'T:\'
)

$Source = 'c:\source'

# Because we are repeating the steps for a KNOWN number of times, the FOR loop is
# the best choice.
# In this form it will start with $RemainingAttempts equal to 3 il will keep going
# as long as $RemainingAttepts is true, which in this case means "greater than 0",
# will reduce $RemainingAttempts by 1 AFTER checking if it still $true==greater
# than 0
for ($RemainingAttempts = 3; $RemainingAttempts ; $RemainingAttempts--) {

    Write-Host "Remaining Attempts: $RemainingAttempts"

    # By using ToArray we are, basically, working on a temporary virtual copy of
    # $DestSSD updated each loop, which let us modifying the original.
    # There might be more efficient ways to manage this, but this seems the
    # easiest to read and given the size of the collection the difference is
    # probably imperceptible
    $DestSSD.ToArray().foreach({

            # not necessary but makes easier to read.
            $Disk = $_
            Write-Host "Accessing SSD: $Disk"

            if (Test-Path $Disk) {
                robocopy $Source $Disk /COPY:DAT /R:0 /np /tee /LOG+:"C:\Documents\logs\SSD_LOG.log"
                Write-Host 'Copy successful!'

                # .Remove() returns a boolean in 5.1 but not in 7.x
                # Nullying it to maximise compatibility
                $null = $DestSSD.Remove($Disk)

                # check if the now updated $DestSSD has still elements, and
                # loads the value in $TotalSSD
                if ($RemainingSSD = $DestSSD.Count) {
                    Write-Host "Remaining SSDs to check: $RemainingSSD"
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host 'Last SSD copy finished!'
                    # Break does, in fact, break the loop only.
                    # Exit, otherwise, would close the whole script
                    break
                }
            }
            else {
                Write-Host 'Copy failed... Trying again later!'
            }
        })

    # instead of waiting at the end of a single failure, it's better to wait at
    # the end of a single loop(unless we have completed the job and broken out)
    Write-Host 'waiting 1 sec'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
# if $DestSSD.Count is $true as in: greater than 0, some Test-Path failed
if ($DestSSD.Count) {
    Write-Host 'Max attempts reached!' 
    Write-Host ('Failed to copy on drives {0}' -f ($DestSSD -join ', ') )
}


Thanks for detailed step by step notes and improvements in the logic, I will look into it more over the weekend.

I want to push back a bit on this - I don’t disagree with your answer, but Powershell goes to quite significant lengths with its automatic type conversion to avoid users needing to worry too much about the type system, and per your “point 1”, using generics requires you to declare the type up front (or just use “object” :-)). I think saying you should avoid ArrayList might mislead new Powershell users into the mindset that they should always use generics, and imho, that’s not necessarily a good thing as ArrayList is fine for a lot of scenarios…

@mclayton I'm a new user and I've been told to never/avoid use Array List and use generic lists instead haha

@mclayton to be fairt, that's what Microsoft itself says. For all purposes and intents they deprecated ArrayList because List[object] is more efficient while dealing with heterogeneous collections AND you can also use it with known homogeneous collections increasing efficiency and type-security. I honestly cannot think a situation where ArrayList is better than any form of List except, perhaps, if you need to know the index of the object you just added at the same time as you are adding it. Which is QUITE the extreme case, and you could just dericve it with a .Count
